# Boson ladder operator $n+1$ factor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, second-quantization, normalization

Looking at Boson creation and annihilation operators, I [come across](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Creation_and_annihilation_operators_for_reaction-diffusion_equations) that

\begin{equation}
b_a|n_\alpha\rangle=\sqrt{n_\alpha}|n_\alpha-1\rangle
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
b_a^+|n_\alpha\rangle=\sqrt{n_\alpha +1}|n_\alpha+1\rangle.
\end{equation}

For number $n_\alpha$ of particles in a state $\alpha$

Where do the factors come from?

Answer (score 2):

Let $$|n\rangle = \frac{(a^{\dagger})^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |0\rangle$$ be the n'th normalized eigenstate and recall the commutation relation for bosonic creation/annihilation operators, $[a, a^{\dagger}] = 1$. Then we have $$a|n\rangle =  \frac{ a \,(a^{\dagger})^n}{\sqrt{n!}} |0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\big([a, (a^{\dagger})^n] - (a^{\dagger})^n a\big)|0\rangle,$$ by definition of the commutator. But $a|0\rangle = 0$ by definition, and by induction one can show that $$[a, (a^{\dagger})^n] = n(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}.$$ Thus $$a|n\rangle = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^{\dagger})^{n-1}|0\rangle = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n!}}\sqrt{(n-1)!}|n-1\rangle = \sqrt{n} |n-1 \rangle. $$ A similar exercise shows the equality for the raising operator.

Comment: Thank you, your factor $\sqrt{(n-1)!}$ made me realise how to do it I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following explains it:

\begin{equation}
|n_\alpha\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n_\alpha!}}(b^+_\alpha)^{n_\alpha}|0\rangle
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b^+_\alpha|n_\alpha\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n_\alpha!}}b^+_\alpha(b^+_\alpha)^{n_\alpha}|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_\alpha!}}(b^+_\alpha)^{n_\alpha+1}|0\rangle
\end{equation}

and since

\begin{equation}
|n_\alpha+1\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n_\alpha+1)!}}(b^+_\alpha)^{n_\alpha+1}|0\rangle
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
b^+_\alpha|n_\alpha\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{(n_\alpha+1)!}}{\sqrt{n_\alpha!}}|n_\alpha+1\rangle=\sqrt{n_\alpha+1}|n_\alpha+1\rangle
\end{equation}

Comment: So does anyone know what these factors are for? Or is it just a side effect of the operators?

Comment: They're just consequences of insisting that your eigenstates be normalized, and the operator algebra of the ladder operators.